How to create a new table from existing table in Excel?
I have an existing master table, tbl_A. I need to narrow it down into a new table, tbl_B. tbl_B should only have a selection of tbl_A's columns and filter out some of tbl_A's rows, and any changes made to tbl_A should apply to tbl_B. How can I achieve this?
I've thought about pivot tables, but I don't want to summarize tbl_A or do any numerical analysis on it, I just want to sample from it. I've tried using filter(), but that doesn't make a new table. Since I do want to summarize tbl_B with a pivot table, I'd rather not manually change the bounds for that summary's inputs anytime tbl_A gets a new row.
How can I get this done?

Update: additionally, tbl_B must be on a different sheet than tbl_A, and would preferably be in the same workbook as tbl_A. Power Query can be used with this requirement if I select the current .xslx as the source.
Would that reference break if the filename changes or if the file changes location?

Use Power Query to filter rows and select your columns.

if you don't want a pivot tabe to summarize, don't put anything into the values section.

@bugdown Power Query seems excellent. I'd like A and B to be in the same workbook, different sheets. I can make B by referring to the file, but can't refer to A directly since they're different sheets. If I refer to the file, will the reference break if the filename changes or the file changes location?

Yes, if you change the file name or location the query will break, but this is true of other reference methids, as well. If query A references the file, query B can reference query A and filter rows and remove columns. Note that this all happens in memory. You can Refresh All if the source data changes, such as getting new rows. To handle file name or location changes you can set up parameters and enter names and paths manually if they change.

Do you have data examples to provide? What version of Office are you using now? If you can use the FILTER function, maybe the formula can help you solve the problem as well.
